# Use poll to distinguish connection from message

Tags: c, sockets, ipc

I'm trying to write a program which either reads from a socket or from stdin. If socket then print to stdout (to user), otherwise print to socket. So far I'm using `poll` to awake program when there's activity on either, my problem is that after the initial connection, `poll` always reports activity on the socket, even though client hasn't written anything else.

Is there any way to distinguish between "someone has connected to the socket" and "someone put a message on the channel"? Looking through man pages for `poll`, `select` and others I don't really see an appropriate flag.

If there is no appropriate flag, what would be a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do ?

What I currently have is something like below. When I enter something in stdin, `poll` returns and the loop determines the activity was on the socket (wrong).

edit: There's other issues at well but this is what I'm struggling with right now.

```
    /* blocking accept for first and only connection */
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    /* poll stdin and newsockfd */
    struct pollfd fds[2];
    fds[0].fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    fds[0].events = POLLIN;
    fds[1].fd = newsockfd;
    fds[1].events = POLLIN;
    ioctl(newsockfd, FIONBIO, (char *)&on); /* int on = 1 */
    while (1) {
        int rc = poll(fds, 2, -1);
        if (rc <= 0)
            exit(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (fds[i].revents == 0)
                continue;

            if (fds[i].revents != POLLIN)
                exit(1);

            if (fds[i].fd = newsockfd) {
                n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
                printf("read %d chars from newsockfd: %s\n", n, buffer);
            } else if (fds[i].fd = STDIN_FILENO) {
                read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 255);
                n = dprintf(newsockfd, "%s", buffer);
                printf("wrote %d chars to newsockfd: %s\n", n, buffer);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Read up on the difference between `=` and `==`...

Comment: Thanks for spotting it, I know the difference.

Comment: `if (fds[i].revents != POLLIN)` is not the correct way to test the value of `revents`.  `revents` is a bitmask, and it can contain other events than what you ask for (`POLLERR`, `POLLHUP`, and `POLLNVAL`), so use the `&` operator instead when testing for individual events: `if (fds[i].revents & POLLIN) { readable } else { not readable }`

Comment: Also, on your `(d)printf()` calls, `buffer` is not null terminated, so use `%.*s` instead of `%s` so you can pass `n` as the buffer size to avoid going out of bounds: `printf("read %d chars from newsockfd: %.*s\n", n, n, buffer);` ... `n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 255); n = dprintf(newsockfd, "%.*s", n, buffer); printf("wrote %d chars to newsockfd: %.*s\n", n, n, buffer);`

Comment: Alright thanks. Got something running but the original problem persists, i.e. to distinguish events. If I kill the client then server registers an event on socket all the time, and similarly if server is killed. Would need a way to distinguish with greater granularity. Could validate what's on buffer but then there's no point in using ```poll``` in the first place.